# Hiding a div on scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I know there is plenty of similar topics, but I cannot find a good answer.

I am trying to hide a div on the mobile scroll, but with no success so far.

```
<div class="sticky">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row top">
            <div class="col-md-12 taCenter">
                <div class="logotip">
                    <a href="<?= get_site_url() ?>"><img class="desktop_logo" src="http://dev128.nadlani.si/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/NaDlani_284_94.png"></a>
                    <a href="<?= get_site_url() ?>"><img class="mobile_logo" src="http://dev128.nadlani.si/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/NADLANI_2019_mobile.png"></a>
                    <div class="mobile-like">
                        <script>
                            var senseSpeed = 5;
                            var previousScroll = 0;
                            $(window).scroll(function(event) {
                                var scroller = $(this).scrollTop();
                                if (scroller - senseSpeed > previousScroll) {
                                    $("div.mobile-like").filter(':not(:animated)').slideUp();
                                } else if (scroller + senseSpeed < previousScroll) {
                                    $("div.mobile-like").filter(':not(:animated)').slideDown();
                                }
                                previousScroll = scroller;
                            });
                        </script>
                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/nadlani.si/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-trigger-wrapper">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <?php
                            foreach ($tree as $item) {
                                echo '<li>';
                                echo '<a href="' . $item["url"] . '">';
                                echo $item["title"];
                                echo '</a>';
                                echo '</li>';
                            }
                        ?>
                   </ul>
                    <div class="trigger">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the current code. When I try to scroll, nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try overflow:hidden;

Comment: use something like this `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    overflow:hidden;
  }
}`

Comment: Instead of using the scroll event the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is much better suited for this problem.

Comment: @ibrahimyanik yes, but with no success... I am really not sure what could be the problem since the code seems fine?

Comment: @Dadinho28 did you try my code?

Comment: @xmastertje i did, no luck.

Comment: @Dadinho28 it's css btw not jquery

Comment: @xmastertje i know, but still, no luck.